# How can i remove a class from a div and add a new class with jQuery to that div when a specific div doesnt exist in the page?

Tags: jquery

As the title describes what I m trying to do is to remove the class `half-width` and add the new class `full-width` to a div with `id="planetdata1"` when the div with `id="a12"` doesn't exist anymore in the page.

In this example, there's the div with `id="a12`"

```
 <div id ="a12">Hey! i am the div that i hide my self sometimes</div>
 <div id="planetdata1" class="half-width"></div>
```

But when the div with `id="a12"` is not displayed at the page then i want the div with the `id="dataplanet1"` to become like that:

```
 <div id="planetdata1" class="full-width"></div>
```

How can I do that with jQuery? I tried to find an answer before I post my question but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: Do you want to do this class swapping when a12 gets removed?

Comment: a12: 1) will be removed from DOM 2) or just hidden('is not displayed at the page')?

Comment: I really can't understand why my question down-voted. I 'm not an expert developer but i 'm really trying to learn day by day step by step.

Comment: @Designer How expert you are is unrelated to how good your question is.  Accepting an answer that explicitly does not address your clarification is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do this when the page load, try this

```
$(function(){
   if($('#a12').length == 0){
      $('#planetdata1').removeClass('half-width');
      $('#planetdata1').addClass('full-width');
   }//end if
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the element is on the page or not, you can do something like this:

```
$("#a12").length
```

The above will return `0` if the div is not in the page, and `1` if it is. Plus, to remove/add a class from/to the element, you can do the following:

```
$("#planetdata1").removeClass("half-width").addClass("full-width");
```